# "Windows was unable to complete the format" when trying to format HP USB flash drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a 2 GB HP flash drive, when  I right click and select the format option , I get a warning dialogue that says

> Windows was unable to complete the format

How do I format a flash drive?

Answer (score 2):

You often cannot format a USB thumbdrive from windows formatter - especially with Windows XP or older. I'd suggest using the [HP drive format tool](http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm) - the one I have linked is an older, better version to format it.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass that error with **Computer Management**. Execute `compmgmt.msc` on the command line:

[image]

When the application opens, under **Storage** select **Disk Management**. this will search for all the drives attached to the computer. Now find your flash drive in the middle window and right-click on it, and finally choose **Format**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to my answer at this question:

[How do I reformat an unmountable/unrecognised/unformatted USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/343291/how-do-i-reformat-an-unmountable-unrecognised-unformatted-usb-drive/912338#912338)

You could try to format your drive with diskpart.